# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 in a LSTM model

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I have this code:

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
MAXLEN = 16
TRUNCATING = 'post'
PADDING = 'post'
OOV_TOKEN = "<OOV>"
MAX_EXAMPLES = 160000
TRAINING_SPLIT = 0.9

# Initialize an empty numpy array with the appropriate size
EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX = np.zeros((VOCAB_SIZE+1, EMBEDDING_DIM))

# Iterate all of the words in the vocabulary and if the vector representation for 
# each word exists within GloVe's representations, save it in the EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX array
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = GLOVE_EMBEDDINGS.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX[i] = embedding_vector

# Define the model

def create_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, maxlen, embeddings_matrix):
    
  
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
        #  Set the Embedding layer when using pre-trained embeddings
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen, weights=[embeddings_matrix], trainable=False),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 6, activation='relu'),
       # tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=4),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy']) 

    return model.summary()

model = create_model(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, MAXLEN, EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX)

# Train the model 
history = model.fit(train_pad_trunc_seq, train_labels, epochs=20, validation_data=(val_pad_trunc_seq, val_labels))
```

which brings me this error,

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Create your untrained model
----> 2 model = create_model(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, MAXLEN, EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX)
      4 # Train the model and save the training history
      5 history = model.fit(train_pad_trunc_seq, train_labels, epochs=20, validation_data=(val_pad_trunc_seq, val_labels))

Input In [25], in create_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, maxlen, embeddings_matrix)
      4 def create_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, maxlen, embeddings_matrix):
      5     
      6     ### START CODE HERE
----> 8     model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
      9         # This is how you need to set the Embedding layer when using pre-trained embeddings
     10         tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen, weights=[embeddings_matrix], trainable=False),
     11         tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     12         tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 6, activation='relu'),
     13        # tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=4),
     14         tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
     15         tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
     16         tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
     17         tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
     18     ])
     20     model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
     21                   optimizer='adam',
     22                   metrics=['accuracy']) 
     24     ### END CODE HERE

File ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:629, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    627 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    628 try:
--> 629   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    630 finally:
    631   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py:214, in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    212   ndim = shape.rank
    213   if ndim != spec.ndim:
--> 214     raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    215                      'is incompatible with the layer: '
    216                      f'expected ndim={spec.ndim}, found ndim={ndim}. '
    217                      f'Full shape received: {tuple(shape)}')
    218 if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    219   ndim = x.shape.rank

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 64)
```

So I need to have an input parameter such as input = (?,?,?) for my LSTM layer instead of (None, 64), but what should it be?

I have also tried to change GlobalAveragePooling1D() to AveragePooling1D(pool_size=4).
It brings up the summary but gives me a different error:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_3 (Embedding)     (None, 16, 100)           12829400  
                                                                 
 dropout_3 (Dropout)         (None, 16, 100)           0         
                                                                 
 conv1d_3 (Conv1D)           (None, 11, 64)            38464     
                                                                 
 average_pooling1d_1 (Averag  (None, 2, 64)            0         
 ePooling1D)                                                     
                                                                 
 lstm_3 (LSTM)               (None, 64)                33024     
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 520       
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 12,901,417
Trainable params: 72,017
Non-trainable params: 12,829,400

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [24], in <cell line: 5>()
          2 model = create_model(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, MAXLEN, EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX)
          4 # Train the model and save the training history
    ----> 5 history = model.fit(train_pad_trunc_seq, train_labels, epochs=20, validation_data=(val_pad_trunc_seq, val_labels))
    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it before, but refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling1D. It seems that if the input tensor is of dimension n, then GlobalAveragePooling 1D output a tensor with dimension n-1.  GlobalAveragePooling1D do pooling along an axis, so it reduces the dim.
If the output tensor shape after conv1d is (None, 11, 64), then the output for GlobalAveragePooling 1D is (None, 64), which is of dimension 2, not 3, so the first attempt results in an error.

Things are different for AveragePooling1D. It does local average pooling, so the dimension of output tensor is the same as input tensor.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AveragePooling1D

For the second question, refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#summary. `model.summary()` just prints a string summary of the network. (I guess the function return value is `None`). You should return a model with `return model`, because class `Model` has the method `fit`